# What interpolation methods used in cv::cvtColor() demosaicing

Tags: opencv, image-processing, demosaicing

I would like to reproduce the `cv::cvtColor()` function that converts a raw Bayer image into an `RGB` image. There are several different ways like `COLOR_BayerBG2BGR`, or `COLOR_BayerBG2BGR_VNG`, and `COLOR_BayerBG2BGR_EA`. However, I can not find any information on what interpolation method each of those approaches uses. There should be some references to publications or patents. Anyone knows?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

OpenCV, as the name already suggests,  is open source. Just read the source code if you are interested in what is happening under the hood. Or copy it if you want to "reproduce" the function...

https://github.com/opencv/opencv

Usually its just the average of the neighbouring values. what fancy interpolation method would you expect?

Comment: Actually, it seems to work pretty good as for a simple linear interpolation, so I did expect some fancy interpolation and possibly some after-processing. How do I find the source code?

Comment: @Naz you find the source code in the repository on GitHub which I provided a link to. Then you use the search function to find what you need. https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4fd00c1ae1968115670d631121363f7dbaa71922/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp#L9694